# Ruby on Rails: shared method between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a few of my models have a privacy column, is there a way I can write one method shared by all the models, lets call it is_public?

so, I'd like to be able to do object_var.is_public?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One possible way is to put shared methods in a `module` like this (`RAILS_ROOT/lib/shared_methods.rb`)

```
module SharedMethods
  def is_public?
    # your code
  end
end
```

Then you need to include this module in every model that should have these methods (i.e. `app/models/your_model.rb`)

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SharedMethods
end
```

**UPDATE**:

In Rails 4 there is a [new way](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns) to do this. You should place shared Code like this in `app/models/concerns` instead of `lib`

Also you can add class methods and execute code on inclusion like this

```
module SharedMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :public, -> { where(…) }
  end

  def is_public?
    # your code
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def find_all_public
      where #some condition
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: self.class would give you whatever the class is in the context of that method being called.  So, for instance, if you did YourModel.new.is_public?, self.class would be YourModel.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this by inheriting the models from a common ancestor which includes the shared methods.

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def is_public?
    # blah blah
   end
end

class ChildModel < BaseModel
end
```

In practice, [jigfox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262980/jigfox)'s approach often works out better, so don't feel obligated to use inheritance merely out of love for OOP theory :)

Comment: I want to do it this way. But I can't make it work... :(

Comment: does not work fore me, created a shared class TestClientManager and now it tries to create a table for it: `Table 'socha-webapp.test_client_managers' doesn't exist`